# Can't install PHP extension mongo with Composer

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, composer-php

How to install PHP extension Mongo with composer in mac machine? I use following command to install PHP extension with composer.

```
composer install --prefer-source
```

I got the following exceptions.

```
vagrant@vagrant:/var/www$ composer install --prefer-source
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb 1.4.x-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.4.x-dev].
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.4.x-dev requires ext-mongo ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb dev-master -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[dev-master].
    - doctrine/mongodb dev-master requires ext-mongo ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.4.x-dev requires ext-mongo ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm dev-master requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.3 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.4.x-dev].
    - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb-odm dev-master -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[dev-master].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Note:

I have installed MongoDB in mac machine, installed version is

```
Shyleen:~ shyleenrodrigues$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v3.4.6
```

Comment: Have you tried googling? http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.homebrew.php

Answer (score 2):

> doctrine/mongodb 1.4.x-dev requires ext-mongo ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.

It seems that the php mongodb extension is not installed. So please see [mongodb documentation php driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/#drivers).

You can simply install this extension via [pecl](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb), if `php-dev` package is installed - depending on your php version.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev // for example on ubuntu linux!!
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Restart php and rerun the composer and check its output.

Ok, on mac it seems like a bit different as you can read [here](https://manas.tungare.name/blog/how-to-install-mongodb-for-php-on-mac-os-x/) (12.).